# is it possible to return a value with synchronizationcontext .send

Tags: c#, messagebox, multithreading, synchronizationcontext

We have a need to use SynchronizationContext to return a value (specifically a MessageBox DialogResult) via Send (we don't want asynch via 'Post'). Just not sure of the syntax.
We were having issues with MessageBox appearing behind main window which was thought to be caused by not being able to access the main forms IWin32Window value easily...We're using this, but to be honest I'm uncomfortable with it.

```
 DialogResult dr;
 SynchronizationContext synchContext;

 //in main forms constructor
  {
       ...
       synchContext = AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext;
  }

 void workerThread( object obj, DoWorkEventArgs args)
 {

   // SynchronizationContext passed into worker thread via args
   sc.Send( delegate {dr = MessageBoxEx.Show( "Yes or no?", "Continue?",   MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question );},null);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an `object` into the delegate that you pass to Send.

So here is what I would do:

```
class DialogResultReference
{
    internal DialogResult DialogResult { get; set; }
}
class YourClass
{
    static void ShowMessageBox(object dialogResultReference)
    {
        var drr = (DialogResultReference)dialogResultReference;
        drr.DialogResult = MessageBoxEx.Show("Yes or no?", "Continue?",   MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    }

    // ... You just remove dr from the class
    SynchronizationContext synchContext;

    //in main forms constructor
    {
        ...
        synchContext = AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext;
    }

    void workerThread(object obj, DoWorkEventArgs args)
    {
        var drr = new DialogResultReference();
        sc.Send(YourClass.ShowMessageBox, drr);
    }
}
```